# Kill Apache process gracefully

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

In in Ubuntu 12 one Apache process is hogging CPU to 100%. How to kill it gracefully?

I don't want to use `service apache2 restart` as it closes all the existing connections.

Can I use `kill -15 pid` to kill just that pid **gracefully**?

Answer (score 1):

Its been a while, but I believe the following will do the trick.

Debian/Ubuntu

```
apache2ctl graceful
```

or

```
sudo apache2ctl graceful
```

Comment: I think there is mandatory -k option with it

Comment: Nah...  not required.  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apachectl.html